# When I come back from my journey, I will tell you the places I "have visited/visited" - which one makes sense?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

**Example 1**

> When I come back from my journey, I will tell you the places I **have visited**.

**Example 2**

> When I come back from my journey, I will tell you the places I **visited**.

Which tense should we use? It seems to me that present perfect tense would be more suitable because I have not started my journey yet.

Comment: Neither version sounds obviously wrong to me.